# SDN 6 - Neo4j Projections with subclasses

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have a class called entry. It has an ID and four language objects:

```
@Node
public class Entry {
   @Id
   private String id;

  
   private Language de;
   private Language fr;
   private Language it;
   private Language en;
}
```

That language class has a title and a list of content classes:

```
@Node
public class Language {
   @Id
   private String id;

  
   private String title;
   private List<Content> content;
}
```

Said content is where the problems begin to arise. The class itself looks like this (simplified of course):

```
@Node
public class Content {
   @Id
   private String id;

  
   private String order;
   private boolean published;
   // ...
}
```

But that class also has many classes which extend from it:

```
@Node
public class TextContent extends Content {
     private String text;
}
@Node
public class ImageContent extends Content {
     private String imageUrl;
     private int imageSize;
}
```

At the moment we don't use projections, but we would like to switch our code to those. The Problem being that we don't know if SDN can differentiate between different nodes by label because in the database the content node has the labels "Content" and for example "TextContent". But of course you can't use the normal ContentProjection for that:

```
interface ContentProjection {
     String getOrder();
     boolean getPublished();
}
```

Since there many of the properties like "text" or "imageUrl" would be missing. Is there a way to solve this?